# xunit Run each test in parallel

Tags: c#, testing, .net-core, xunit

I have a requirement to speed up my tests a lot

Is there a way to do this with xunit and have the tests run in parallel within a class?

I know that by default XUnit cant run tests inside a test collection in parallel but this is what I need to do?

Im using .NET Core 3.1

Paul

Comment: See https://xunit.net/docs/running-tests-in-parallel